# Requesting a file with node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the root of the app (http://site.com), that runs when requesting the domain. If I wanted to add only one file say robots.txt (http://site.com/robots.txt) to be requested using this http server, how would I do that? It would pull from the contents of robots.txt and echo it out.

```
var http = require('http');
        http.createServer(function (req, res) {
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
          res.write('homepage');
          res.end('');
        }).listen(process.env.VMC_APP_PORT || 1337, null);
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest using [sendfile](http://blog.std.in/2010/09/09/using-sendfile-with-nodejs/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing such a functionality manually, you can build your application with http://expressjs.com/ framework and use static middleware documented at http://expressjs.com/guide.html to server static files. But I would personally prefer to put Nginx in front of Node to serve static file, because it has proven to be efficient for this job and it is all about configuration rather than programming then. Configuration can be different depending on the specific purpose and environment, but mine is documented at http://skovalyov.blogspot.com/2012/07/deploy-multiple-node-applications-on.html